# How to set the timeout for a rest service call in Web.Config

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, web-config, timeout

I have a WCF application, that's making an external REST call to gather some data. The call is being made by an included dll, so we have no say in this call; we only have the url. I'm trying to set a timeout in Web.Config file for this (particular) external call. So setting the timeout generically for all the REST calls doesn't work in this case. Can someone point me in the right direction, what should I write in the Web.Config?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

you might want to specify a particular `WebHttpBinding`

Comment: The REST call is being made from another dll (obfuscated) so I only have the url the call is being made to.

Comment: How are  you making the call to the service?

Comment: I'm just calling a method of the dll, which makes the call.

Comment: And since you don't know how the DLL is making the call, it's going to be difficult to set the timeout, or any other property of the call.

Comment: We have figured out another way of doing it. For the reference, we used another class which inherits the one that we're calling from the dll and used reflection to set some properties. As far as I understand there's no way of setting the timeout without knowing / having the Service interface; which was the main problem.